# Extract certain columns from data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

My data frame looks like this:

```
   x s1   s2 s3  s4
1 x1  1 1954  1 yes
2 x2  2 1955  1  no
3 x3  1 1976  2 yes
4 x4  2 1954  2 yes
5 x5  3 1943  1  no
```

Sample data:

````
df <- data.frame(x=c('x1','x2','x3','x4','x5'),
                    s1=c(1,2,1,2,3),
                    s2=c(1954,1955,1976,1954,1943), 
                    s3=c(1,1,2,2,1),
                    s4=c('yes','no','yes','yes','no'))```
````

Is it possible to extract the data frame's columns containing integers `1` to `3`? For example, the new data frame would look like:

```
 newdf
   x s1 s3
1 x1  1  1
2 x2  2  1
3 x3  1  2
4 x4  2  2
5 x5  3  1
```

Is it possible to change the `s1` and `s3` columns to 0 or 1 depending on whether or not the value in the column is 1? The altered data frame would then look like:

```
newdf2   
 x s1 s3
1 x1  1  1
2 x2  0  1
3 x3  1  0
4 x4  0  0
5 x5  0  1
```

Comment: You say you want to extract the columns that contain integers between 1 and 3, but then you retain the `x` variable, which has string data -- do you want a different rule there? (Or is the `x` variable just the special one that you want to retain?)

Comment: The x variable is just a special one I would like to retain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### base R

```r
newdf <- df[, unique(c("x", names(which(sapply(df, function(z) is.numeric(z) & any(c(1, 3) %in% z)))))), drop = FALSE]
newdf
#    x s1 s3
# 1 x1  1  1
# 2 x2  2  1
# 3 x3  1  2
# 4 x4  2  2
# 5 x5  3  1

newdf[-1] <- lapply(newdf[-1], function(z) +(z == 1))
newdf
#    x s1 s3
# 1 x1  1  1
# 2 x2  0  1
# 3 x3  1  0
# 4 x4  0  0
# 5 x5  0  1
```

Walk-through:

- first, we determine which columns are numbers and contain the numbers 1 or 3:

  ```r
  sapply(df, function(z) is.numeric(z) & any(c(1, 3) %in% z))
  #     x    s1    s2    s3    s4 
  # FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  ```

  This will exclude any column that is not numeric, meaning that a `character` column that contains a literal `"1"` or `"3"` will *not* be retained. This is complete inference on my end; if you want to accept the string versions then remove the `is.numeric(z)` component.
- second, we extract the names of those that are true, and prepend `"x"`

  ```r
  c("x", names(which(sapply(df, function(z) is.numeric(z) & any(c(1, 3) %in% z)))))
  # [1] "x"  "s1" "s3"
  ```
- wrap that in `unique(.)` if, for some reason, `"x"` is also numeric and contains 1 or 3 (this step is purely defensive, you may not strictly need it)
- select those columns, defensively adding `drop=FALSE` so that if only one column is matched, it still returns a full `data.frame`
- replace just those columns (excluding the first column which is `"x"`) with 0 or 1; the `z == 1` returns `logical`, and the wrapping `+(..)` converts logical to 0 (false) or 1 (true).

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  select(x, where(~ is.numeric(.) & any(c(1, 3) %in% .))) %>%
  mutate(across(-x, ~ +(. == 1)))
#    x s1 s3
# 1 x1  1  1
# 2 x2  0  1
# 3 x3  1  0
# 4 x4  0  0
# 5 x5  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you expect :

```
my_df <- data.frame(x=c('x1','x2','x3','x4','x5'),
             s1=c(1,2,1,2,3),
             s2=c(1954,1955,1976,1954,1943), 
             s3=c(1,1,2,2,1),
             s4=c('yes','no','yes','yes','no'))

my_df$end <- apply(my_df, 2, function(x) paste(x, collapse = " "))
my_df <- my_df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(end2 = paste(str_extract_all(string = end, pattern = "1|2|3", simplify = TRUE), collapse = " "))
my_var <- which(my_df$end == my_df$end2)
my_df[, my_var] <- t(apply(my_df[, my_var], 1, function(x) ifelse(test = x == 1, yes = 1, no = 0)))
my_df <- my_df[, c(1, my_var)]
```